# Javascript CSS single selection toggle (vertical list)

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to create the following but am not sure what would be the best way to go about it.

I want a vertical list of items on a web page.
Each item is click-able.
When the user click once one list item, I want to show that it has been selected (by showing a button image in the background. When the click the same item again or clicks any other list item, I want to remove that image and if another item was clicked, the selection image is shown behind that item.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you opposed to jQuery or traditional javascript? I can show you a jQuery example very quickly; normal js would take a tad more effort.

Comment: I don't understand why would someone do a )-1) to this question?

Comment: Don't worry about it. What's a little disappointing is it was -1'd, but no votes to close or comments as to why. I wish the -1 wouldn't be applied until the voter followed-up with an action.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is especially pleasurable to do in jQuery. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HgVmm/3/

HTML:

```
<ul id='items' class='selectable'>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
// For a single list to act independent of other lists:
$('ul.selectable li').live('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

// For all `selectable` lists to act together:
$('ul.selectable li').live('click', function () {
    $('li.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

CSS:

```
ul.selectable li { cursor: pointer; }
ul.selectable li.selected { background: red; } /* Style to taste */
```

Comment: What about removing the selection if clicked on the even count? (2nd, 4th, etc. consecutive click?) _"When the click the same item again or clicks any other list item, I want to remove that image..."_

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks Brad for pointing that out. There is one more small thing. Actually I will have two or three vertical columns. So I may need to use multiple UL elements. In that case, how would the script need to be changed? Only one selection allowed even if there are many columns... Thanks both.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Another good point; he'd still need a special event listener to be able to de-select items since that functionality is not built in to jQueryUI.

Comment: why include jQueryUI if you don't need to... you're just adding a lot of extra javascript that will probably never get used.  (especially considering the avg developer only uses like 10% of what jQuery has to offer to begin with, let alone adding jQueryUI on top of that)

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ79X/), *along with a [re-factored version](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ79X/2/)*

```
// catch a click on any of the <li> items
$('li').click(function(){
    // store a reference to the specific <li> that
    // was clicked.
    var $li = $(this);

    // toggle the class (if it's applied, it's removed.
    // if it's removed, re-apply it)
    $li.toggleClass('clicked');

    // Now, if it's applied, remove the class from any
    // other <li> (single item clicked at a time)
    if ($li.hasClass('clicked')){
        $li.siblings().removeClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brad for your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

@ssdesign; i know you accepted an answer but may be you can check this one 
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/HgVmm/4/

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```